# Table header not receiving CSS (I think)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have some simple HTML here:

```
<table class="table shipment" id="payItems">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th class="sku">Varekode    </th>
       <th class="productName">Produkt</th>
      <th>Pris</th>
   <th>Antall</th>
   <th style="text-align: right; padding-right: 80px;">Sum</th>

  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
...content...
 </tbody>
</table>
```

And this CSS:

```
 table#payItems.table thead th
{
 border: 0;
}
```

Because it's in a wrapper div with rounded corners, and the top th has a top border I want to get rid of, but any combination of th, tr, thead doesn't seem to get rid of this border.

Comment: The CSS selector `table#payItems.table` is massively redundant - `#payItems` should do fine

Comment: I almost made an answer to this, and suddenly, I discovered that you had made an answer yourself. You should really move the answer from your question, and add it as an answer to your own question, and then mark that as the accepted answer. This way, it will be easier for others to read, and give a good solution to others that have similar issues.

Comment: Egentlig var jeg skal gjøre det senere, fikk bust med arbeidet:) Men jeg skal nå, takk:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with:

```
#payItems thead, #payItems tr { border-top: 0; }
```

Thanks to Yi Jiang for inspiration.